# Is there a method in Sitecore's utilities to format a numerical file size in a friendly way?

Tags: sitecore-api

The title pretty much says it all. I feel like I've come across a method in the past that does something like:

```
long fileSize = 524288000;
string prettyFileSize = Sitecore.SomeUtility.ConvertPrettyFileSize(fileSize);
```

Resulting in `prettyFileSize` containing `"512MB"`.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You are correct, you probably have come across this. The `Sitecore.StringUtil, Sitecore.Kernel` class contains a number of methods for managing strings.

The two methods in particular are:

`StringUtil.GetSizeString(long size)`

This method takes in a long value *524288000*, and returns a string representation of "512MB"

`StringUtil.ParseSizeString(string value)`

This method takes in a string value like "512MB" and returns the long representation of that size, 524288000.

An Example:

```
    using Sitecore;

    public long GetLongValue(string valueSize)
    {
       return StringUtil.ParseSizeString(valueSize);
    }

    public string GetStringSize(long size)
    {
       return StringUtil.GetSizeString(size);
    }
```

Comment: Just a note, as I needed to answer this for somebody else, but the first method here (GetStringSize) was marked as obsolete in version 9.2. You now need to use Sitecore.MainUtil.FormatSize(long, bool) in the Kernel DLL as of 9.3.